# Sort multiple columns in pivot

Tags: vba, excel

Excel 2013. This is my PIVOT table where the item labels are in tabular form. What I am trying to do is sorting as follows :

1. column 1 sort order should be Red, Amber, Green
2. Column 2 sort order should be A-Z
3. Column 3 sort order should be PCC3,2,1,0

How can I accomplish this? I tried more sort options. No use. Can this be done using excel VBA?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need VBA, just create your custom list.
https://exceljet.net/tips/how-to-sort-a-pivot-table-with-a-custom-list